# Different nginx config for different environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, redirect, nginx, dokku

I have a Rails app hosted in two different servers (both with dokku) for production and staging environments. The first one is hosted in `www.mywebsite.com.br` and the second one in `www.staging.mywebsite.com.br`.

We use a SSL certificate in production so I wrote

`return 301 https://www.mywebsite.com.br$request_uri;`

in my `nginx.conf.sigil` file so that every path redirects to the https URI. All working fine.

But now when I go to the staging environment, all URIs also redirect me to the `https://www.mywebsite.com.br` instead of `http://www.staging.mywebsite.com.br`. It makes sense, since I'm redirecting all requests in that line, but I can't seem to find a solution to configure my `nginx.conf.sigil` file for those two different needs.

Thanks a lot in advance and happy new year =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a slightly separate nginx conf file for each server/environment, substituting in the correct domain name for each. You can see https://serverfault.com/questions/250476/how-to-force-or-redirect-to-ssl-in-nginx for more details and examples.